# Need Help in Achieving the required Output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a requirement to convert Data from certain tables into a specific format.
Could you please help me out achieve the desired output?

Below link contains an Excel Attachment which holds the following information:
[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx4o5myaTlN1QzF6aHR3d1JGRms)

1. Tab : Input-Output --> Contains the Structure of the Source and the Target Table
2. Tab : Create Scripts --> Create scripts to create all the tables
3. Tab : Insert Scripts --> Insert script to insert the data into the Source Tables

**Edit (Code) which I tried:**

```
TYPE subline_col_c_rectype IS RECORD
   (
ID_C    VARCHAR(75), 
Col_C1  VARCHAR(75), 
Col_C2 VARCHAR(75)

   );

   TYPE subline_col_c_tabtype IS TABLE OF subline_col_c_rectype
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;   


   TYPE line_rectype IS RECORD
   (

   ID_A VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_A1    VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_A2    VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_A3    VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_A4    VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_A5    VARCHAR(75), 
   ID_B  VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_B1    VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_B2    VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_B3    VARCHAR(75), 
   Col_B4    VARCHAR(75), 
    Col_B5 VARCHAR(75), 
    Col_C    subline_col_c_tabtype,
        Col_D    subline_col_c_tabtype
);

   TYPE line_tabtype IS TABLE OF line_rectype
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Was able to store the records in associative array line_tabtype but not sure how to expand the child records and store it in the target table.

Comment: Yes I understand that the design of POC_TARGET_C is poor but that is what I need to achieve.. Actually Data in the Target table will be passed to ETL tool which will upload the data in the Target system so can't really change the Target table design..

Comment: I tried using associative array to store the Target table data...Storing  Columns ID_A to Col_B5 was straight forward and I was able to store the Data in that target associative array. For Columns - ID_C,Col_C1, Col_C2 and ID_D, Col_D1,Col_D2 I created associative arrays and stored them in that target associative array(array inside an array).. Now all the rows are in single line.. I am facing problem in expanding those child associative arrays..

Comment: You should show what you've tried in your question, and also explain the rules for the translation (and why you're using PL/SQL for this). Providing the data set-up info is great but it should be in the question not an external link; as should the expected result.

Comment: The code you added just defines types;and you still haven't explained your logic, or the relationships between the tables - are you looking for IDs matching? Why are so many values null? Etc.

Comment: A) Where ID Matches corresponding values should come and where it doesn't null should come. For E.g in Table POC_Source_D we don't have ID_D = 1 values so in target table columns ID_D to Col_D2 is blank.. B) No many NULLS are there because we will need to extract the  data in the target table in .txt format and that will be passed to the ETL Tool which will then load it to the Target System... the ETL Tool reads the data in such tree format only so that is why the design is such..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID_A, COL_A1, COL_A2, COL_A3, COL_A4, COL_A5, ID_B, COL_B1, COL_B2, COL_B3, COL_B4, COL_B5, ID_C, COL_C1, COL_C2, ID_D, COL_D1, COL_D2
  FROM (SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id_a ORDER BY col_a1) rn_a
          FROM POC_SOURCE_A a) a
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT NVL (x.id_x, d.id_d) id_y, NVL (x.rn_x, d.rn_d) rn_y, x.*, d.*
                          FROM (SELECT NVL (b.id_b, c.id_c) id_x, NVL (b.rn_b, c.rn_c) rn_x, b.*, c.*
                                  FROM (SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id_b ORDER BY col_b1) rn_b
                                          FROM POC_SOURCE_B b) b
                                       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id_c ORDER BY col_c1) rn_c
                                                          FROM POC_SOURCE_C c) c
                                          ON b.id_b = c.id_c AND b.rn_b = c.rn_c) x
                               FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT d.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id_d ORDER BY col_d1) rn_d
                                                  FROM POC_SOURCE_D d) d
                                  ON x.id_x = d.id_d AND x.rn_x = d.rn_d) y
          ON y.id_y = a.id_a AND y.rn_y = a.rn_a
ORDER BY NVL (ID_A, ID_Y), NVL (rn_a, rn_y)
```

EDIT:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE line_tabtype IS TABLE OF POC_TARGET_C%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   target line_tabtype;  
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_a id
                FROM POC_SOURCE_A
              UNION
              SELECT DISTINCT id_b id
                FROM POC_SOURCE_B
              UNION
              SELECT DISTINCT id_c id
                FROM POC_SOURCE_C
              UNION
              SELECT DISTINCT id_d id
                FROM POC_SOURCE_D
              ORDER BY 1)
   LOOP
      FOR c2 IN (  SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY col_a1) rn
                     FROM POC_SOURCE_A a
                    WHERE ID_A = c1.ID
                 ORDER BY COL_A1)
      LOOP
         target (c2.rn).ID_A := c2.ID_A;
         target (c2.rn).COL_A1 := c2.COL_A1;
         target (c2.rn).COL_A2 := c2.COL_A2;
         target (c2.rn).COL_A3 := c2.COL_A3;
         target (c2.rn).COL_A4 := c2.COL_A4;
         target (c2.rn).COL_A5 := c2.COL_A5;
      END LOOP;

      FOR c2 IN (  SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY col_b1) rn
                     FROM POC_SOURCE_B b
                    WHERE ID_B = c1.ID
                 ORDER BY COL_B1)
      LOOP
         target (c2.rn).ID_B := c2.ID_B;
         target (c2.rn).COL_B1 := c2.COL_B1;
         target (c2.rn).COL_B2 := c2.COL_B2;
         target (c2.rn).COL_B3 := c2.COL_B3;
         target (c2.rn).COL_B4 := c2.COL_B4;
         target (c2.rn).COL_B5 := c2.COL_B5;
      END LOOP;

      FOR c2 IN (  SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY col_c1) rn
                     FROM POC_SOURCE_C c
                    WHERE ID_C = c1.ID
                 ORDER BY COL_C1)
      LOOP
         target (c2.rn).ID_C := c2.ID_C;
         target (c2.rn).COL_C1 := c2.COL_C1;
         target (c2.rn).COL_C2 := c2.COL_C2;
      END LOOP;

      FOR c2 IN (  SELECT d.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY col_d1) rn
                     FROM POC_SOURCE_D D
                    WHERE ID_D = c1.ID
                 ORDER BY COL_D1)
      LOOP
         target (c2.rn).ID_D := c2.ID_D;
         target (c2.rn).COL_D1 := c2.COL_D1;
         target (c2.rn).COL_D2 := c2.COL_D2;
      END LOOP;

      FORALL I IN target.FIRST .. target.LAST
        INSERT INTO POC_TARGET_C VALUES target(i);

      target.delete();
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Mottot Query is working fine. I wanted to achieve the output via PL-SQL Code as this was just the POC and number of tables in the actual system will be more than 200 so can't really use the SQL Query but surely this will help... thanks again :-)

Comment: @PankajArora Try the PL/SQL after EDIT

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into poc_Target_C 
select id_A, col_A1, col_A2, col_A3, col_A4, col_A5, isnull(id_B,'') as id_b, isnull(col_B1,'') as col_B1, isnull(col_B2,'') as col_B2, 
isnull(col_B3,'') as col_B3, isnull(col_B4,'') as col_B4, isnull(col_B5,'') as col_B5, isnull(id_C,'') as id_C, isnull(col_C1,'') as col_C1, 
isnull(col_C2,'') as col_C2, isnull(id_D,'') as id_D, isnull(col_D1,'') as col_D1, isnull(col_D2,'') as col_D2 
from poc_source_A left outer join poc_source_B on poc_source_A.id_A=poc_source_B.id_B left outer join 
(poc_source_C left outer join poc_source_D on poc_source_C.id_C=poc_source_D.id_d 
and poc_source_C.col_C1=('C'+substring(poc_source_D.col_D1,2,len(poc_source_D.col_D1)))) on poc_source_A.id_A=poc_source_C.id_C;
```

This might help you out to insert data in required format.

Comment: Just using SQL query won't work for me as this is just the POC I am doing...actual number of table is more that 200.. so I need to achieve  the desired output via some PL-SQL Code only..